# Drag and Drop: get target attributes (ID, inner HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm using drag and drop. There's one element that I can drop at two different targets. For code simplicity, I thought it would be better to have only one drop function, inside which I look up where the element was dropped. However, I'm new to Javascript DOM manipulations and don't know how to achieve this.

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.innerHTML);
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var username = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var type = ev.target.innerHTML;  //<====== ?? what's the proper way to do this?
    alert("Adding " + username +" to chat. Type: "+ type); 
    socket.emit('add to convo',username);
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div id = "dragboxes">
      <div id="samechatbox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <p> Add to <b>This</b> Chat </p>
      </div>
      <div id="newchatbox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <p> Add to <b>New</b> Chat </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

So inside the drop function, I would like be to able to retrieve the target IDs, either "samechatbox" or "newchatbox".

Comment: Easily solved. My bad. Just added a second parameter to the function which becomes: drop(ev,type)... I guess it's hard to thing clearly sometimes. But if you have a nicer way to do it simply using target.something I'm still interested :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `target.id`. I think that's what you're looking for. You shouldn't need `innerHtml` for what you've described.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Just target.id, or event.target.id ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant `event.target.id`. I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same using sortable.

this is the following code. i think it will help you:

```
 $(function() {
                $( ".droppable" ).sortable({
                    connectWith: ".droppable",
                    receive: function(e, ui) {
                        alert($(e.target).attr('id'));  //it give the id of dropped location
                        console.log(ui.item[0].id);  // it gived the id of dropped object
                    }
                })
            });
```